# Can you take an "inhale" of air?

Tags: verbs, nouns, vocabulary

In the following sentence

> “I’m okay,” I mutter, finally managing to take a sharp inhale of
>   air.

is it okay to use "inhale" as a noun here, or should it only be a verb? I feel like "inhale" is the verb and "inhalation" is the noun, but when I type "inhale of air" into Google, I get 32,000 hits, so I guess it may be acceptable.

Should this usage now be considered correct or has it not (yet?) become common  enough to be considered so?

Comment: Hello, Monique. Your question would be better if you added the names of a couple ... of dictionaries that don't list 'inhale' as a noun.

Comment: See [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/95921?rskey=tewDQV&result=1#eid) for inhale as a noun.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use inhale as a noun. As it is not grammatically correct.

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inhale) does not list a noun.
[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inhale) does not list a noun.
[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inhale) does not list a noun.

Of course in literature there are always mavericks.

Take Alan Lightman's, [Einstein's dreams](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=T16eBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT51&lpg=PT51&dq=Clouds%20overhead%20come%20together,%20move%20apart,%20come%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20together%20again%20with%20the%20pace%20of%20successive%20exhales%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20and%20inhales.&source=bl&ots=_FLDFFgE2Y&sig=JYvMVKTRB60Ol49fG1oFHPOlVrM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM9u7drZzOAhUoBMAKHUWwCL4Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Clouds%20overhead%20come%20together%2C%20move%20apart%2C%20come%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20together%20again%20with%20the%20pace%20of%20successive%20exhales%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20and%20inhales.&f=false), for example: -

> Clouds overhead come together, move apart...with the pace of
>   successive exhales and inhales.

I would opt for:

> “I’m okay,” I mutter, finally managing to take a sharp gasp of air.

Then again, there is such a thing as poetic licence, and you can use it as you please!

*Poetic Licence*

> The freedom to depart from the facts of a matter or from the
>   conventional rules of language when speaking or writing in order to
>   create an effect. [1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/poetic-licence)

Comment: Thanks so much Gary! I had wanted to avoid the word "gasp" as I feel like I've already overused it in my novel (a thriller). I wanted something sharp, but not necessarily as loud or dramatic as "gasp". I will play around with the sentence and see what I can come up with. Thanks!

Comment: Consider using *sharp **intake** of air*.

Answer (score 1):

The noun form of the verb inhale is *[inhalation](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inhalation)*, defined as "an act or instance of inhaling."

Your sentence might be better using a *breath*, or a *lungful of air*.